# What's the proper way to dispatch action inside epic?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-observable

What is the proper way to dispatch `operationReset()` inside of redux-observable epic?

Should I import actual store and use it?

[It used to be like this, but following store is deprecated, and will be removed](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-1)

```
// show operation failed message
(action$, store) => action$.ofType(OPERATION_FAILURE).map(() => (error({
    title: 'Operation Failed',
    message: 'Opps! It didn\'t go through.',
    action: {
        label: 'Try Again',
        autoDismiss: 0,
        callback: () => store.dispatch(operationReset())
    }
}))),
```

Comment: What's the `error` function there?

Comment: Notification action @KyleKelley https://github.com/gor181/react-notification-system-redux#actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably raises a larger question about how one should do notifications with callbacks, since it means you're sending a non-JSON serializable function as part of an action.

I'll assume you want to match the react notification system still. There's a way you can do this using `Observable.create`:

```
(action$, store) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(OPERATION_FAILURE),
    mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.create(observer => {
        observer.next(
          error({
            title: "Operation Failed",
            message: "Oops! It didn't go through.",
            action: {
              label: "Try Again",
              autoDismiss: 0,
              callback: () => {
                // Send off a reset action
                observer.next(operationReset());
                // Close off this observable
                observer.complete();
              },
              // If the notification is dismissed separately (can they click an x?)
              onRemove: () => observer.complete()
            }
          })
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

NOTE: I still wouldn't want to send callbacks as part of actions.  Amusingly, one of my projects uses that notification system component too -- we have epics that will add notifications and clear them based on actions. All actions stay pure, and the notification system is a controlled side effect.